# admin panel save option with ajax

Tags: plugins, admin, ajax, customization

I create custom options in the admin panel but I have some difficulties to save it with ajax.

I can't get the php script with action variable in ajax script.

Here all my scripts:

in functions.php :

```
require_once ($admin_path . "theme-options.php");

function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_register_script('theme-options', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/inc/theme-options.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox'));
    wp_enqueue_script('theme-options');
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox'); 
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

in theme-options.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'add_general_settings');
function add_general_settings(){

        if(get_option('logo-url') == ""){
            update_option( 'logo-url', 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/logo.png' ); 
        }

        if(get_option('favicon-url') == ""){
            update_option( 'favicon-url', 'http://' );
        }

        if(get_option('google-analytics') == ""){
            update_option( 'google-analytics', 'Goolge Analytics Here...' );
        }

    if(!empty($_POST)) {

        $logourl = $_POST['logofile'];
        $faviconurl = $_POST['favicon'];
        $analytics = $_POST['googleanalytics'];

        if(!empty($logourl)){
        update_option( 'logo-url', $logourl );
        }
        if(!empty($faviconurl)){
        update_option( 'favicon-url', $faviconurl );
        }
        update_option( 'google-analytics', $analytics  );
    }
}
```

and in theme-option.js :

```
jQuery('#button-general').click(function() {

    jQuery('#savemessage').html('Loading...');

    var logofile = jQuery('#logofile').val();
    var favicon = jQuery('#favicon').val();
    var google_analytics = jQuery('#google-analytics').val();

    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        logofile: logofile,
        favicon: favicon,
        googleanalytics: google_analytics,
    };
    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        jQuery('#savemessage').html('General Settings Saved').hide(2000);
    });
});
```

If I try to alert(action) , my_action is undefinied... Because it's not present in the source code...

Comment: As for the last sentence: In your code, `action` is a property of `data` --> `alert(data.action);` will print `'my_action'`.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it seems that with ajax call it don't pass through the php code. Nothing is saved...

Comment: I really don't understand why nothing is save in the database...

Comment: try returning something from your php- add some sanity checks to echo your data so you know it's sending what you expect, use your browser's console to check for errors and inspect the request and response.

Comment: I find my problem, it was a jquery conflict between thickbox and the last version of jquery. Now it's working fine. My script is correct finally. Thanks for help.